# Kotlin + ModelMapper: DefaultConstructorMarker

Tags: kotlin

В Java для маппинга сущностей в DTO и обратно я пользуюсь ModelMapper. Часть его функционала выглядит так:

```
mapper.createTypeMap(Continent.class, ContinentDto.class)
                .addMappings(m -> m.skip(ContinentDto::setPlanet)).setPostConverter(toDtoConverter());
```

Конкретно меня интересует часть кода `m -> m.skip(ContinentDto::setPlanet)`, где мы задаём мапперу, что при мапинге сущности в DTO поле planet не надо сетить. Более подробно эта часть кода выглядит так:

```
.addMappings(m -> m.skip(new DestinationSetter<ContinentDto, Object>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(ContinentDto destination, Object value) {
        destination.setPlanet((Long) value);
    }
})).setPostConverter(toDtoConverter());
```

Я в Котлине недавно, поэтому написал что-то такое:

```
.addMappings { it.skip { destination, value: Long -> destination.user = value } }
.postConverter = toDtoConverter()
```

IDE не ругается, но при компиляции валится с какой-то непонятной ошибкой.

```
Caused by: org.modelmapper.internal.ErrorsException: null
    at org.modelmapper.internal.Errors.toException(Errors.java:254) ~[modelmapper-2.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.internal.ProxyFactory.proxyFor(ProxyFactory.java:86) ~[modelmapper-2.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.internal.ProxyFactory.proxyFor(ProxyFactory.java:72) ~[modelmapper-2.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.internal.ReferenceMapExpressionImpl.skip(ReferenceMapExpressionImpl.java:84) ~[modelmapper-2.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.modelmapper.internal.ConfigurableMapExpressionImpl.skip(ConfigurableMapExpressionImpl.java:73) ~[modelmapper-2.3.4.jar:na]
    at ru.xpendence.slimer.mapper.impl.UserParamsMapper$init$1.configure(UserParamsMapper.kt:29) ~[classes/:na
```

Поставил брейкпоинт на ErrorsException и поймал следующий текст ошибки:

```
Cannot map final type ru.xpendence.slimer.dto.UserParamsDto.
```

Полез обратно по цепочке рантайма и нашёл точку, из которой падает в ошибку:

```
if (Modifier.isFinal(type.getModifiers()))
      throw errors.invocationAgainstFinalClass(type).toException();
```

Сделал классы open, теперь прилетает следующее:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invisible parameter type of
>   kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker arg6 for public
>   ru.xpendence.slimer.dto.UserParamsDto$ByteBuddy$5aqRCzYE(java.lang.Long,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Double,java.lang.String,java.time.LocalDateTime,int,kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker)

Как я понял, компилятор обнаружил какой-то DefaultConstructorMarker и не может разглядеть его параметр. Подскажите, в чём дело?

На всякий случай, класс UserParamsDto:

```
open class UserParamsDto(

        var user: Long? = null,
        var height: Int? = null,
        var weight: Double? = null,
        var gender: String? = null,
        var birthDate: LocalDateTime? = null

) : AbstractDto()

open class AbstractDto(

        var id: Long? = null,
        var created: LocalDateTime? = null,
        var updated: LocalDateTime? = null
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если используете в конструкторе (или в методе) параметры с значениями по умолчанию, то компилятор Kotlin создаёт невидимый синтетический конструктор (или метод) с таким вот служебным параметром-маркером. Возможны варианты:

1. Если ваш фреймворк не споткнётся об это, добавить аннотацию `@JvmOverloads` к конструктору

```
open class AbstractDto @JvmOverloads constructor(
    var id: Long? = null,
    var created: LocalDateTime? = null,
    var updated: LocalDateTime? = null
)
```

Тогда будет фактически создано несколько конструкторов `AbstractDto()`, `AbstractDto(Long)`, `AbstractDto(Long, LocalDateTime)`, `AbstractDto(Long, LocalDateTime, LocalDateTime)`, но всё равно добавлен один синтетический `AbstractDto(Long, LocalDateTime, LocalDateTime, DefaultConstructorMarker)`. Возможно, фреймворк этим удовлетворится.

2. По-старинке не использовать параметры по умолчанию, а просто поля и дефолтный конструктор

```
open class AbstractDto {
    var id: Long? = null
    var created: LocalDateTime? = null
    var updated: LocalDateTime? = null
}
```

3. Самому написать несколько конструкторов

```
open class AbstractDto(
    var id: Long?,
    var created: LocalDateTime?,
    var updated: LocalDateTime?)
{
    constructor() : this(null, null, null)
}
```

4. Написать багрепорт по фреймворку, чтобы он не падал на синтетических параметрах :)

Answer (score 0):

Если решения, предложенные в другом ответе не сработали - есть очень грязный хак, который мне помог

Пишем точно такой же класс точно в таком же пакете, но в своём проекте, и при этом делаем его public:

```java
package kotlin.jvm.internal;

/**
 * Очень грязный хак, см:  
 * https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/991071/kotlin-modelmapper-defaultconstructormarker
 * https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20869
 */
public final class DefaultConstructorMarker {
    private DefaultConstructorMarker() {
    }
}
```

Тогда ButeBuddy находит именно его, а он у нас public
П.С. В котлине [заведена бага](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20869) по этому поводу
П.П.С: Котлин хорошо обходится без мапперов вообще, тк в нём всё отлично реализуется и стандартными средствамии типа extension-методов и конструкторами с именованными параметрами. Поэтому ModelMapper и этот хак может понадобится только если вы переходите с java на kotlin, иначе лучше просто не исползьуйте никаких либ маппинга